# Excel IF, Then Statement

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, sum

I am looking to IF 2 separate columns then count 2 other columns. So I am trying to define information from shift so 1st, 2nd, 3rd & then individual departments, so when you IF let's say 1st Shift for Dept #4100 then count Column P & Q.

I've googled this formula and played, but I feel I'm missing something. Almost like this should be a IF with a Then statement, but that didn't seem to work

=SUMIF("K2:k500,1")&("N2:N500,4100") then (P2:P500+Q2:Q500)

Comment: =SUMIF("K2:k500,1")&("N2:N500,4100") then (P2:P500+Q2:Q500)

Comment: `=SUMIFS(P2:P500,K2:k500,1,N2:N500,4100)+SUMIFS(Q2:Q500,K2:k500,1,N2:N500,4100)`

Comment: Awesome - Thank you Scott - that worked perfectly. I try to work things out before asking, only way one learns, but again - Thanks Pat

Comment: Thank you for contributing Q @PatrickLoomis, some suggestions: 1) word question much more clearly (2nd sentence isn't actually a sentence, 1st one makes little sense, that's the bulk of your question, we really only have your function to decipher and even that was updated in the commentary, not the question where it should be placed) 2) provide sample data - always helps to speed up accurate solution by making Q clearer - e.g. provide a screenshot showing cols/rows and place in question 3) state Q clearly/concisely to avoid ambiguity.  Your Q doesn't have any ? mark..

Answer (score 0):

There's a far quicker / parsimonious way than 'multiple sumifs' statements which you appear to have adopted based upon commentary above:

```
sum((p2:q500)*(k2:k500=1)*(n2:n500=4100))
```

What's nice about this set up is that it's far quicker/easier to extend to encompass multiple adjacent columns - so long as you make sure to have corresponding 'criteria' (e.g. `k2:k500=1`, `n2:n500=4100` etc.) specified as req. (the alternative of attempting to write out 10,20, or even 50 sumifs seems somewhat daunting, let alone tractable from an audit/review viewpoint...